# Friendly URL showing index when redirecting, I want to show mysite.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My URL rewrite is working fine, the only thing is that after I click **HOME** to go back, the URL is showing `mywebsite.com/test/index` and I want get rid of the index to show only `mywebsite.com/test/`. This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rscares/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(rscares/.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Where does the link point? `<a href="??what here??">`

Comment: It points to index.html

Comment: So, point to `<a href="/">` or `<a href="/test/">` whichever is your root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rscares/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(rscares)/(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Right on! Again, thank you very much @anubhava for your help!